# Proper terminology of left and right Kan extensions as residuals?

Tags: category-theory, kan-extensions

I was recently reading about Kan extensions and the codensity monad. Apparently you can think of the codensity monad as a bit like an endomorphism monoid internal to a functor category.

The right Kan extension is a bit like an exponential in a functor category.

$$[F, G](a) = \forall b, (a \rightarrow F(b)) \rightarrow G(b) $$

And you can "eval" and "curry" things as well.

$$\text{eval} : [F, G] \circ F \Rightarrow G$$

Left kan extension would be a "coexponential" like object. You can think of it as a little like a tuple of a value and a continuation.

$$(F - G)(a) = \Sigma_b\, F(b) \times (G(b) \rightarrow a) $$

It strikes me "exponential" isn't quite the right terminology. Composition certainly isn't a Cartesian product.

So left and right Kan extensions would be coresiduals and residuals?

I'm interested in exploring further so I want to know the precise and accurate terminology and notation instead of the hodgepodge of "its a bit like an exponential" I have right now.

Comment: Essentially the [same question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/352051/kan-extensions-inside-a-monoidal-category) was asked here on MathOverflow.

Comment: @varkor thank you that's a great place to start looking up things from.